# Stylesheet not loading using php readfile()

Tags: php, html, css

I want to redirect all traffic to one page where I decide what to output based on the URL the user entered. So far it works fine, the only thing that does not work is loading the stylesheet.
Currently I tried all of it locally with XAMPP.

I reduced the code to a minimum to point out the problem.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!test\.php).+)$ /test.php [L]
```

Everything except test.php is rewritten to test.php

test.php:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// remove any slashes in front of the path
$path = ltrim($path, '\\');
$path = ltrim($path, './');

if (pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "css") {
    readfile($path);
}
else {
    echo("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
    echo("<html>\n");
    echo("<head>\n");
    echo("<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/test-style.css' />\n");
    echo("</head>\n");

    echo("<body>\n");
    echo("<h2>Test Heading</h2>\n");
    echo("</body>\n");

    echo("</html>\n");
}

?>
```

I check the file extension, if it is CSS, I output the file, if not I write some HTML code line by line.

test-style.css:

```
h2 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

If I open any address in the browser, the HTML is shown but the stylesheet is not applied. Everything else works (I can load a favicon, javascript works), but not the stylesheet. I could directly output the code inside '' tags but of course, that is not a good solution.
If I use the inspector of firefox I see that the stylesheet is there and if I change a line it suddenly applies.

Any ideas why this is not working or maybe a suggestion on how to achieve the desired results in a different way? Cleaning the browser cache or changing browser has no effect.

Comment: Wouldn't the style sheet be before any other HTML.

Comment: You are reading the CSS file and outputting it to the browser BEFORE you output the DOCTYPE etc.

Comment: Look at where you output it in the ELSE ????

Comment: Also if you get a `css` extension, you dont output any HTML so there is nothing to see on the page

Comment: What is wrong with the link to the stylesheet inside the head?

Comment: Nothing :) but thats not the problem is it its the IF bit thats causing issues not the ELSE

Comment: you probably need to send the correct headers like e.g. content-type

Comment: What I thought to achieve: write the html line by line, the browser gets it and asks for the stylesheet which is then offered by my php file using 'readfile()'. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: If I type stylesheets/test-style.css into the address bar it outputs the css file, so this is working.

Answer (score 1):

@apokryfos found the solution: I had to send the content-type before outputting the CSS.

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

Thank you all for your help.